# How symbols helps to avoid name collision in object in js?

Tags: javascript, object, symbols

As symbol is a unique identifier, they helps us to avoid over-writing the same name property in object.

Like suppose, there is an object named user which is used in many different programs.

```
let user = {
     name :  "ram",
     id : 5,
};
```

So now, suppose this user object is used in another program (lets call it pro1), if we want to add a property named id to it, we will use symbol id, like this -

```
let id = Symbol();
user[id] = 2;
```

So the previous id property is not over-written in user object.

BUT NOW SUPPOSE,

If user object have already symbol id property, and it is used in another program which have not defined the symbol id, then there simply will be error as the symbol id is not defined.

Then my question is how symbol help to avoid naming collisions in object in JavaScript????

I'm literally unable to grasp the concept behind it. Please clarify it.

Comment: Just be aware that `let id = Symbol(); user[id] = 2;` _does not_ assign the value `2` to `user.id`.

Comment: The second program can *also* do `let id = Symbol(); user[id] = 3;` and that would work. There are now going to be two symbol properties - one set at `2`, the other at `3`.

Comment: Every new symbol is unique so you could do this `user = { [Symbol()]: 2, [Symbol()]: 2 }` and it would be valid... but pointless

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*it is used in another program which have not defined the symbol id*". Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Bergi lets suppose this user object have symbol id, now this user object is used in another program, which have not defined the symbol id or created the symbol id in first place, so in this program, user object will cause error as it contains symbol which even not defined or created in first place. So is it wrong practice to directly write symbol property inside object or i should assign the symbol property from outside of object to it. Or how should i deal with it???

Comment: What "error" will be produced in "this other program" exactly?!

Comment: @HimanshuRai No, there's no error. There's just an unused property in that object which the program doesn't know anything about and which it won't try to access even by accident.

Comment: @Bergi no there is an error coming.  Run this code please-  let user = { [id]: 5 } , there will be error

Comment: @HimanshuRai But you supposed that the user object was created in the first program which did define a symbol for `id`, and then the object was passed to a second program that does not define (and use) such a symbol. So there is no code like `{ [id]: 5 }` in the second program at all.

Comment: @Bergi got it! Thankyou so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take for example, an app which has some data about albums and does *stuff* with that data. (Warning: Everything that follows is massively simplified and highly contrived).

Say we have a module for "Sharing my musical taste with my friends" and "Ordering a song" and both modules want to mark the track as **processed** so that you don't end up with duplicate copies or shout about it to your friends more than once.

The module might look like this:

```
const processed = Symbol('processed');

function shareWithFriends(track) {
    if (track[processed]) { return };
    /* do suff */
    track[processed] = true;
}

export default shareWithFriends;
```

Then you could:

```
import shareWithFriends from './shareWithFriends.js';
import orderSong from './orderSong.js';

const song = { /* meta data */ };

shareWithFriends(song);
orderSong(song);
```

Both modules can modify the metadata without mistakenly reading the other modules *processed* symbol .